# ActiveStorage generate attachement url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried to use `ActiveStorage` with one attachment. I was able to upload an attachment.

My issue is to generate the URL. I am using `url_for`

```
class Template < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_archival readonly_when_archived: true

  before_archive

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :fields, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :fields, allow_destroy: true

  has_many :contracts
  has_one_attached :image

end

<%= url_for(@template.image) %>
```

I have got this error

```
undefined method `active_storage_attachment_path' for
#<#<Class:0x007fa1de477520>:0x007fa1defa8b88>
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this work? I am stuck at the same point, i have tried the answer posted here but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
@template.image.url
```

Source: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activestorage/0.1

Comment: unfortunately this does not work and leads to an error NoMethodError: undefined method `generate' for nil:NilClass

Comment: This has since been removed in the lastest Rails 5.2

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're on the old gem, before it was merged into Rails. If you do

`bundle show activestorage`

I think it'll say you're using gems/activestorage-0.1

Try bundling edge rails:

`gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git'`

and if that doesn't blow up your whole application, you'll be able to access the more recently written methods that you're hoping to use.